# How to have an identity column for a temp table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to have an identity column for a temp table in SQL?

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table '#T'
>   either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is
>   inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

I am getting SQL Syntax error for the below block.

```
 if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#t') is not null  
   drop table #t

create table #t
(
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [TotalCount] int,
  [PercentageComplete] nvarchar(4000)
)

insert into #t
  select totalcount, percentagecomplete from table_a
```

Comment: What error are you getting? it works for me.

Comment: I included the error.. explicit error

Comment: You must have identity_insert on then as the error says

Comment: `INSERT INTO #T(TotalCount, PercentageComplete)`. Always specify your column lists, even in the rare case when they happen to match (and in this case, they don't -- the engine won't leave out `ID` just because it's an identity).

Comment: @JeroenMostert while I agree with specifying the columns, the query as stands works so long as identity_insert is off. As in the engine does leave out id.

Comment: @DaleBurrell: So it does! Well, that's... rather pretty awful. Chalk up another one for the vagaries of T-SQL. (At least it's consistent in the sense that it does not care what ordinal position the `IDENTITY` column is in -- it will simply behave as it if's not there, then proceed to match the rest by ordinal.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your query after table declaration

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #t OFF
```

This should fix it. The following code works on my machine

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TotalCount] INT,
    [PercentageComplete] NVARCHAR(4000)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #t OFF 

INSERT INTO #t
    SELECT
        totalcount, percentagecomplete 
    FROM
        table_a
```